# Django filter many to many object using list Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to filter the objects based on many to many field.

```
profiledata = UserProfile.objects.get(user=newdata)
role = profiledata.role
ib = IdealBehaviour.objects.filter(cbs_role = cbsrole)
a_questions = Questions.objects.filter(Q(role=role) & Q(ideal_behaviour=ib))
```

Here i am not getting a_questions.
While doing this i am getting error.

```
(1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    
(1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

I tried using _in lookup also

```
a_questions = Questions.objects.filter(Q(role=role) & Q(ideal_behaviour_in=ib))
```

Getting error

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'ideal_behaviour_in' into field. Choices are: created_time, id, ideal_behaviour, question, role
```

I dont know what wrong i am doing.
ib is getting filtered properly as IdealBehaviour has many to many relationship with CBSROLE
Please help me out for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need double underline at `__in` and you dont need Q here.

```
a_questions = Questions.objects.filter(role=role, ideal_behaviour__in=ib)
```

Comment: how can i filter the object depending on ideal_behaviour__in which i dont want. ideal_behaviour__in!=ib is it right?

Comment: @Gaurav you can something like ``.exclude(ideal_behaviour__in=ib).filter(role=role)``

Comment: So the statement will be a_questions = Questions.objects.exclude(ideal_behaviour__in=ib).filter(role=role)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your priceless help.